# How to repair the Microsoft Edge Local Storage DevTools?

Tags: blazor, local-storage, microsoft-edge, edge-devtools

I was messing around with Blazor and modifying the Counter example to use protected local storage. Programmatically, everything is working correctly. I can increment and decrement my counter, close the browser, restart Windows, and it retains my count through all of it.

However, when I checked to see what would happen if I overflowed my counter, the Local Storage explorer in the Microsoft Edge Dev Tools no longer displays my key/value pairs. The weird thing is that using the Local Storage still works. The explorer within Edge just no longer allows me to view, add, modify, or delete values. To be clear, before I overflowed the value the Local Storage explorer was working. Now it doesn't work for any sites.

This is what the explorer looks like:

[image: Local Storage appears to be empty]

However, when I type localStorage in the console, it shows there are values.

[image: Console shows Local Storage contains values]

I cleared Edge's cache, ran Repair, and it is still not working. Any additional thoughts on how to repair?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a new issue in Chromium browsers, and currently it hasn't been resolved. Also, no workaround available. The Chromium Team is working on it, and you can provide more information in [this issue thread](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1408031&q=devtools%20local%20storage&can=2).